# O que fazer quando uma pergunta não tem solução?

Tags: debate, comportamento

Fiz a [seguinte pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96164/mesclar-c%C3%A9lulas-excel-via-c%C3%B3digo-delphi) para tentar solucionar um problema e acabei descobrindo que o que quero fazer não é possível. A solução possível para a pergunta passa por mudar a programação que é o que menciono que não quero que aconteça.

Baseado nisso pensei em excluir a pergunta, porém, lembrei do que aconteceu comigo. Se eu tivesse a informação que tenho agora, não perderia tempo procurando uma solução que não existe.

Então outros podem ter a mesma necessidade e acabaria sendo um bom ponto de partida.

O que é mais adequado fazer nesse caso? 
Dar detalhes do porque não tem solução e indicar que é preciso mudar o *approaching*? E se for isso, colocar numa resposta?

Comment: Creio que um [EDITADO] ou [ATUALIZADO] seguido das suas considerações no em torno do problema já resolveria. Nesse caso, este se encontraria no topo da pergunta, pra ter mais destaque. E outra, cuidado ao afirmar que não existe solução. Já cai em muitas armadilhas partindo desta premissa. ;)

Comment: @Marcos lá por uma pergunta não ter solução não quer dizer que ela não seja boa, a maioria das vezes as perguntas muito boas são as que não têm solução fácil. Mantém a pergunta.

Comment: Já agora @Marcos esta pergunta deveria res sido feita no meta, mas deixa ficar aqui, esta será migrada.

Comment: Creio que o melhor seja responder explicando como e pq não é possível fazer isso. Como você mesmo disse, se já tivesse achado essa resposta lhe pouparia tempo, e mais alguém pode precisar da mesma "ajuda".

Comment: @JorgeB. Ainda estou aprendendo a usar o SO. Valeu pela dica.

Comment: Relevante: http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/03/03/stackoverflow-youre-not-alon

Comment: @Randrade Não quer postar isso como resposta?

Comment: @WeslleyTavares Por favor **nunca** coloque coisas como [EDITADO], [ATUALIZADO] ou [RESOLVIDO] no título das perguntas! No corpo também dá pra evitar na maior parte dos casos.

Comment: @bfavaretto, muito obrigado pela orientação! Irei me atentar pra esse conselho sempre.

Comment: Legal, @WeslleyTavares! Se interessar, tem um [guia de estilo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1297) com orientações desse tipo. E faltou eu dizer o motivo de não usarmos essas coisas no título: é porque temos outras maneiras de indicar isso, mais precisas. Assuntos resolvidos têm uma resposta marcada como aceita. Publicações editadas/atualizadas sempre indicam quem editou e quando, com link para o histórico de edição. Então simplesmente não é necessário colocar essas informações no título, melhor aproveitar o espaço pra resumir o tema da pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu estava sem tempo no momento, por isso apenas comentei. Não comentei sobre o "[EDITADO], [ATUALIZADO] ou [RESOLVIDO] " pois você já explicou muito bem aqui.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nestes casos, creio que a melhor solução seja criar uma resposta explicando que a pergunta não possui solução. Claro que não devemos apenas postar que "não tem como fazer", apesar da lógica (e todas as fibras de meu corpo) pedir. 
Só porque não existe uma forma de fazer, não significa que a pergunta não mereça resposta, até porque se você teve essa dúvida, mais pessoas possuem e/ou irão possuir algum dia, então o melhor é deixar em algum lugar para as "próximas gerações".

No SOpt existe vários exemplos parecidos com esse que você comentou. Vamos [utilizar apenas esse para não estender a resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25760/por-que-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-poss%C3%ADvel-definir-uma-interface-com-m%C3%A9todos-est%C3%A1ticos)
Neste caso, o AP já pergunta **"Por que não é possível fazer algo"**, e nas respostas podemos observar que o mesmo encontrou soluções que o atendem, e podemos ver também que existem outros usuários que se beneficiaram com a resposta, pois foi apontado outra forma de fazer a mesma coisa. E se você observar os comentários, poderá ver que o autor estava um pouquinho "equivocado" em afirmar algo.

Resumindo, adicione a resposta, desde que tenha certeza de que se trata, isso acabará ajudando outras pessoas.